# Dispose control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Design:

[image]

If i don't have any land component price/flight prices to be added, i want the system to dispose the unused controls and move up to fill in the empty spaces, but somehow or rather, it became like this.

Result:

[image]

```
if (bf.landComponent != 0.00m)
{
    lblLandComponent.Text = "" + bf.landComponent;
    lblLandComponent.Visible = true;
    lblLandComponentL.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    lblLandComponent.Dispose();
    lblLandComponentL.Dispose();
}

if (bf.flightComponent != 0.00m)
{
    lblFlightComponent.Text = "" + bf.flightComponent;
    lblFlightComponent.Visible = true;
    lblFlightComponentL.Visible = true;
}

if (bf.unitSales != 0.00m)
{
    lblUnitSales.Text = "" + bf.unitSales;
    lblUnitSales.Visible = true;
    lblUnitSalesL.Visible = true;

}

if(bf.rentalCar!=0.00m)
{
    lblCT.Visible = true;
    lblRentalCar_L.Visible = true;
    lblRentalCar.Visible = true;
    lblRentalCar.Text = "" + bf.rentalCar;
}

if (bf.discount != 0.00m)
{
   lblDiscount.Text = "" + bf.discount;
   lblDiscountL.Visible = true;
   lblDiscount.Visible = true;
}

if(bf.packageInclusion!="")
{
   lblPackageInclusion.Text = bf.packageInclusion;
   lblPackageInclusion.Visible = true;
   lblPackageInclusionL.Visible = true;
}
//BF is a class object stored in a session that i put from the previous page.
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Just set visible to false.

Comment: tried that previously, but didnt work.

Comment: I think one of the if condition is executing due to condition. Try to debug each line and also check the design page for the properties of those controls.

Comment: maybe they are NULL not 0.00m? or maybe it's not 0.00m but NaN or 0.0000000000001?

Answer (score 0):

The `Dispose` method is not for the thing you want. Check in the docs to see what it really does.

When you want to hide a control, try setting their Visibility to `false`, or try removing them from their parent container control.

Conditionally setting their `Visibility` to `true` is not enough. In 99% of cases they would be visible anyways, since that's the default value for visibility. You must ensure to either set their initial Visibility to false, or add else clause that will do that.

Comment: Thank you. i will check it out again.